# malloc and free issue

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

So I have this piece of code, I run it a couple of times:

```
void svnViewStatus()
{
    FILE *file;
    int i, j, k, q=0, ok;
    char mystring[100000], *vect[100000], *var, last[12], first[12];
    file = fopen("db_svnViewStatus.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
    }
    else
    {
        i=1;
        while(fgets(mystring, 100000, file))
        {
            if( i > 1) 
            {
                j=1;
                var = strtok(mystring, ";");
                while(var != NULL)
                {
                    if(j==3)
                    {
                        if(i == 2)
                        {
                            strcpy(first, var);
                        }
                        strcpy(last, var);
                    }
                    if(j == 2)
                    {
                        if(q != 0)
                        {
                            ok=1;
                            for(k=0; k<q; k=k+2)
                            {
                                if(strcmp(vect[k], var) == 0)
                                {
                                    *vect[k+1]++;
                                    ok=0;
                                }
                            }
                            if(ok == 1)
                            {
                                vect[q] = malloc(strlen(var)+1);
                                strcpy(vect[q], var);
                                vect[q+1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
                                *vect[q+1] = 1;
                                q = q+2;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vect[q] = malloc(strlen(var)+1);
                            strcpy(vect[q], var);
                            vect[q+1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
                            *vect[q+1] = 1;
                            q = q+2;
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                    var = strtok(NULL, ";");
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("nr: %d \n", i-2);
    printf("first: %s \n", first);
    printf("last: %s \n", last);
    for(i=0; i<q; i = i+2)
    {
        printf("User %s: %d \n", *vect[i], *vect[i+1]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<q; i=i+1)
    {
         free(vect[i]);
    }

}
```

and in the db_svnViewStatus.db I have:

```
NumeRepo:CitateWoodyAllen;DataCreat:12 Nov 2011;Detinator:Ioana;Descriere:Citate ale faimosului regizor Woody Allen
1;Ioana;12 Nov 2011;Woody Allen;What if everything is an illusion and nothing exists? In that case, I definitely overpaid for my carpet.
2;Mihai;12 Nov 2011;Woody Allen;The lion and the calf shall lie down together but the calf won't get much sleep
3;Mihai;13 Nov 2011;Woody Allen;Eighty percent of success is showing up
4;Cristi;23 Nov 2011;Woody Allen;It is impossible to travel faster than the speed of light, and certainly not desirable, as one's hat keeps blowing off
5;Ioana;25 Nov 2011;Woody Allen;I had a terrible education. I attended a school for emotionally disturbed teachers.
6;Cristi;25 Nov 2011;Woody Allen;I will not eat oysters. I want my food dead. Not sick. Not wounded. Dead.
```

But I get this:

"HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#54) at 0x000032E90.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."

Any help?

Also, should I use free after I allocate memory? Why?

Comment: You allocate `vect[q]` and `vect[q+1]`, but you release `vect[0]`..`vect[q-1]`.  Did you allocate what you freed and did you free what you allocated?

Comment: Does your compiler complain about any of these? `xx.c:43: warning: value computed is not used / 
xx.c:78: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’`?  If so, fix them.  If not, turn up the warning level on your compiler - or get a compiler that does complain.  Have you learned about `struct` yet?  If so, use one.  If not, then there's a marginal excuse for what you're doing, but only marginal.  (GCC 4.2.1 / LLVM on MacOS X 10.7.2 with `-Wall -Wextra` produces the warnings shown.)

Comment: where is that? I didn't use %s with int anywhere. what line? And, yes, I learned about struct...But, why would I use struct if I can work with the data directly there?

Comment: The primary problem is at 'line 43' in my previous comment.  You need `if (strcmp(vect[k], var) == 0) { (*vect[k+1])++; ok = 0; }`.  GCC at least warns you about the trouble.  You had `*vect[k+1]++;`, which increments the pointer, not the integer pointed to.  Then all hell breaks loose.  Heed your compiler - and ensure you turn up the warnings level so you get the help you need.

Comment: The `%s` and `int` problem is in the `printf()` near the end; you pass `*vect[i]` which is a char (promoted to `int`, hence the warning), instead of `vect[i]`.  You'd use a structure to save space, and angst.  You have an array of `char *` where you are treating the even indexes as strings and the odd indexes as a pointer to `int`.  You'd be better off with an array of `struct data { char *name; int count; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code compiles cleanly and runs cleanly under `valgrind`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void svnViewStatus(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    int i, j, k, q=0, ok;
    char mystring[100000], *vect[100000], *var, last[12], first[12];
    file = fopen("db_svnViewStatus.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 1; fgets(mystring, sizeof(mystring), file) != 0; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1) /* Skip heading */
            continue;
        char *space = mystring;
        for (j = 1; (var = strtok(space, ";")) != NULL; space = NULL, j++)
        {
            if (j == 3)
            {
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    strcpy(first, var);
                }
                strcpy(last, var);
            }
            if (j == 2)
            {
                if (q != 0)
                {
                    ok = 1;
                    for (k = 0; k<q; k += 2)
                    {
                        if (strcmp(vect[k], var) == 0)
                        {
                            (*vect[k+1])++;
                            ok=0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ok == 1)
                    {
                        vect[q] = malloc(strlen(var)+1);
                        strcpy(vect[q], var);
                        vect[q+1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
                        *vect[q+1] = 1;
                        q += 2;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    vect[q] = malloc(strlen(var)+1);
                    strcpy(vect[q], var);
                    vect[q+1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
                    *vect[q+1] = 1;
                    q += 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("nr: %d \n", i-2);
    printf("first: %s \n", first);
    printf("last: %s \n", last);
    for (i=0; i<q; i = i+2)
    {
        printf("User %s: %d \n", vect[i], *vect[i+1]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<q; i=i+1)
    {
        free(vect[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    svnViewStatus();
    return 0;
}
```

It has several levels less indentation than the original.  Code marching off the right side of the screen is indicative of problems, most often.  As noted in comments, the primary problem was in the expression that was intended to increment an integer via a pointer, but actually incremented the pointer and not the integer.  There are a couple of `for` loops replacing `while` loops so that the loop control is all at the top of the loop.  It is often easier to control a loop that way.

I'm still unhappy with the code.  You're allocating `int` and treating `char *` as `int *`, which on a 64-bit machine means you have an 8-byte pointer pointing to 4 bytes of data (and two `malloc()` calls).  If you used a structure such as:

```
struct data
{
    char *string;
    int   count;
};

struct data vect[5000];
```

With this, you'd only allocate (duplicate) the string into the next element of the structure.  It would be more compact, and there's less danger of getting things wrong.  (You'd write `vect[i].count++;` and it would do what you want with no fuss, no muss.)  And you'd not need to be messing around with `q += 2;` (or `q = q + 2;`).

This code is better, using the structure.  It also checks memory allocations and ensures that the names copied into `first` and `last` do not overflow (and are null terminated).  It still doesn't do a bounds check on the `vect` array to ensure that it doesn't overwrite the end.  If there's an error while reading the file, memory is leaked; clean up would require some care (and a function to do it).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct data
{
    char *string;
    int   count;
};

static void svnViewStatus(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    int i, q = 0;
    char mystring[100000], last[12], first[12];
    struct data vect[50000];
    file = fopen("db_svnViewStatus.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("file open error\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 1; fgets(mystring, sizeof(mystring), file) != 0; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1) /* Skip heading */
            continue;
        char *space = mystring;
        char *var;
        for (int j = 1; (var = strtok(space, ";")) != NULL; space = NULL, j++)
        {
            if (j == 3)
            {
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    strncpy(first, var, sizeof(first)-1);
                    first[sizeof(first)-1] = '\0';
                }
                strncpy(last, var, sizeof(last)-1);
                last[sizeof(last)-1] = '\0';
            }
            if (j == 2)
            {
                int found = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < q; k++)
                {
                    if (strcmp(vect[k].string, var) == 0)
                    {
                        vect[k].count++;
                        found = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (found == 0)
                {
                    vect[q].string = strdup(var);
                    if (vect[q].string == 0)
                    {
                        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
                        return;
                    }
                    vect[q].count = 1;
                    q++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    printf("nr: %d\n", i-1);
    printf("first: %s\n", first);
    printf("last: %s\n", last);
    for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        printf("User %s: %d\n", vect[i].string, vect[i].count);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        free(vect[i].string);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    svnViewStatus();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should allocate memory for terminating zero, like this:

```
vect[q] = malloc(strlen(var)+1);
```

If you fail to allocate an extra byte, `strcpy` will write past the end of the allocated block, causing heap corruption.

Comment: tried that, the program crashes now. If I remove the free thing, it doesn't crash.

Comment: @FinalDestiny `vect[q+1] = 1;` should be `*vect[q+1] = 1;`

Comment: @FinalDestiny Could you please update the question with the changed code, and also show more lines around the error? There are no other issues in the lines that you posted.

Comment: @FinalDestiny You should zero out `vect` before using it, like this: `memset(vect, 0, sizeof(vect))`

Comment: the program still crashes, unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 problems. The first is that you're not allocating enough memory for the string. You need an extra byte for the null terminator.

The other is that you're setting vect [ q + 1 ] to a pointer, then you're overwriting that pointer with the value 1. When you attempt to free it, you're attempting to free the memory at memory location 1. You need to change:

```
vect[q+1] = 1;
```

to

```
*(vect [ q + 1 ]) = 1;
```

Comment: @FinalDestiny: Still crashes after fixing uer1118321's second bug? Nice catch there, I completely overlooked it. Sheesh. :)

Comment: What else is your function doing between the mallocs and frees?

Comment: It reads a file and works with the data from there, adding some users and the number of the actions they did to the vect array..and basically I just create a new entry every time I read a new user..with the code I posted.. and on the users that already exist, I use *vect[k+1]++;

Comment: *vect[i] is a pretty confusing thing to read. Can you think of a better way to write it? vect is an array of pointers to characters. vect [ i ] is a pointer to a character. *vect [ i ] is a character. So you're telling it to print a character, not print the character string pointed to by vect [ i ]. You probably have a similar error in the line *vect[k+1]++;

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating enough memory here:

```
vect[q] = malloc(strlen(var));
```

`strlen(3)` reports just the length of *contents* of the string and leaves out the trailing ASCII `NUL` chraacter that C uses to terminate strings. Any time you see: `malloc(strlen(foo));` **it is almost certainly a bug**. Always write `malloc(strlen(foo) + 1);`. Make that `+ 1` obvious, because any time you *don't* see that `+ 1`, you've probably found a bug.

```
strcpy(vect[q], var);
```

Because `vect[q]` doesn't have enough memory allocated for it, this line overwrote an unrelated byte with the ASCII `NUL` character.

As for `free(3)`ing your memory, most programmers find it very helpful to write the `malloc(3)` and `free(3)` calls *at the same time*, with the same source code check-in, so that features can be added or removed cleanly and easily. Is there an easy and corresponding "tear down" function that corresponds to the function you've just written? `..._init()` functions often have `..._final()` functions, `..._open()` functions often have `..._close()` functions, and so on. These pairs are ideal for memory management.

Comment: tried that, the program crashes now. If I remove the free thing, it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

First, in this expression statement:

```
*vect[k+1]++;
```

you have an operator precedence issue. You probably wanted to do that instead:

```
(*vect[k+1])++;
```

Then in this function call:

```
printf("User %s: %d \n", *vect[i], *vect[i+1]);
```

the type of `vect[i]` is a char pointer. To print the string you don't want to dereference it and probably wanted to that instead:

```
printf("User %s: %d \n", vect[i], *vect[i+1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your last question:

Also, should I use free after I allocate memory? Why?

Yes, you should use free();
If you don't use free() you take the risk of have a memory leak problem.

You should call free() right at the end of the function, before the return statement if you have one.

However, the calling function in your case main, can also call free() when your svnViewStatus() function is finished and returns control to main. This is because it is okay to use a different pointer variable with free(); you just have to make sure that the new pointer stores the same address.  I mean the address of the first byte of the memory block malloc allocated.

And as dasblinkenlight mentioned it, you need to allocate memory for terminating zero.

I hope this help.